# Unity Player movement script getting error CS1061

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a player movement script working using the one on Unity's website but it does not work. im getting the error CS1061.

*"Assets\Scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(44,21): error CS1061: 'float' does not contain a definition for 'y' and no accessible extension method 'y' accepting a first argument of type 'float' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"*

I checked the internet but with my limited knowledge of unity i couldnt quite figure it out.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private bool groundedPlayer;
    private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
    private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
    private float gravityValue = -9.81f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
       
        controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();
            
    } 
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
        if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
        { 
            playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

    Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

    if (move != Vector3.zero)
    {
        gameObject.transform.forward = move;
    }


    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && groundedPlayer)
    {
        playerSpeed.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
    }
   

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    

}
```

this is my code. If anyone can figure out what is wrong? Apparently the problem is something with Classes. But i have no idea what 'y' has to do with Classes.

Comment: Your `playerSpeed` variable is just a `float` - it's a floating point number. It's not a vector. What do you expect `playerSpeed.y` to mean? (Perhaps you just meant `playerSpeed`?)

Comment: Yep this seems to have worked! thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        playerSpeed.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
```

I believe this is supposed to be playerVelocity instead?

```
        playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
```

Comment: This gives a error that says " Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'float' ". comment above made it work

Comment: I dont think the above comment is the desired effect, Looking at your code player speed is a const move speed value, by modifying player speed this will make your character move around faster.

Comment: I test this myself, and it should work fine?

Just to make sure, were you doing

`playerVelocity += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);`

or

`playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);`

Since you need to be doing the bottom one to make sure you are affecting the y coordinate

Comment: Yeah what you wrote now works. I dunno what was wrong cause what i had written is exactly the same as what you wrote now but i got the error, and now it works without a issue. or at least i cant see a difference